# Civilization 5 Trade Arrows

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-brave-new-world

I just need clarification, << means I get that gold/science/production and >> means the other city state/civ/city (the destination) gets the described gold/science/production?

Comment: Can someone explain when two of the same religion is traded what is the benefit?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

Take the trade route between Te-Moak and Milan. It is earning me 19.8 gold, and it is earning Milan 1 gold.

[image]

If you hover the city names you can see an exact breakdown of how this is earned and how it is divided between the two parties.

Comment: Thank you so much, I really needed that clarification just to be positive.

Comment: @MonteCarlo No problem, I was confused too but happened to randomly mouse over them in the trade screen.